# Optimizing PyTorch Code for Efficiency: Seeking Alternative Nested Loop and General Code Improvements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, nested-loops, torch

I want to optimize my code for efficiency in PyTorch. I'm relatively new to PyTorch, and I have included my code below:

```
  def my_fun(input): # input= (80, 5, 1024) => 80 is the batch size and next two are the dimension of the input
    it = 1
    c = 0
    ic = 1
    e_var1 = 15
    n_var2 = 5
    s= e_var1 - e_var2
    temp = torch.zeros((input.shape[0], s, input.shape[2] + input.shape[2]), dtype=torch.float32,
                        device=torch.device('cuda'))
    for i in range(0, input.shape[1] - 1):
        for j in range(iter, input.shape[1]):
            cv = torch.cat((input[:, i, :], input[:, j, :]), dim=1)
            temp [:,counter,:]=cv.view(input.shape[0], -1)
            c+= 1
        it = it + ic

    input_ex = torch.cat((input, input), dim=2)
    v = torch.cat((input_ex, temp), dim=1)
    return v
```

One approach I have considered is implementing an alternative of the nested loop, but I am unsure of how to proceed with it. Additionally, I would appreciate any suggestions on other lines of code that could potentially improve the computational speed of my program.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and cannot be executed. Please fix it and explain what you are trying to achieve (as there may be a completely different but better way).

Comment: @ken thank you for the response. What issue you are getting?